# Central admin has <> less than and greater than tags on top of navigation menu?

Tags: 2013, central-administration

Anyone has any idea what these are?! They appear on some of our servers and client servers with a fresh install. [image]

Comment: looks like some CSS issue. which browser you are using?

Comment: I've noticed this too. Think it's a bug myself.

Comment: Here's where it's coming from: `<span controlid="CentralAdminStatusBar"> &lt;&gt;`